# Initiate method onchange on input

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/hVSTJ/

Why when we run $("#navTop").val("x");​, we don't get alert message? That's what I need. I need to initiate that method everytime input's value changes. Can't figure it out how.

Answer (score 0):

onchange event will not be triggered when you update the value using javascript..

Alternatively, you can call change event when you set the value like below,

Try,

```
$("#navTop").val("x").change();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hVSTJ/1/)

Comment: Is that all what I can do? I use plugin, so it's hard for me to write just chhange()...

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

The only other option is to poll its value or use the keyup event, or call its value just before the submit or something else is interacted with.

There is an html5 new event that will sort this depending on your project

var numPeople = document.getElementById("numPeople");

numPeople.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    var num = numPeople.value;
    ...
}, false);

it a new input event, cool, I not sure how it is supported by the older browsers.

[read more here](http://girliemac.com/blog/2011/11/27/html5-input-events/)